# Perform Explode animation without window transition

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions, android-windowmanager, android-window

setting the window transition with

```
 getWindow().setEnterTransition(new Explode());
 getWindow().setExitTransition(new Explode());
```

but the result is weird, the window items are entering from a side of the window. It's like `Explode()` animation combined with `Slide()` 
How to do simple explode transition?